# fprintf doesn't write anything

Tags: c, file, printf, file-handling, filehandle

I have this code:

```
105 void draw_detections(char * image_file_name, image im, int num, float thresh, box *boxes, float **probs, char **names, image *labels, int classes)
 106 {
 107     int i;
 108     FILE * fptr;
 109     char filename[100];
 110     strcpy(filename,"output/");
 111     strcpy(filename,image_file_name);
 112     strcpy(filename, ".txt");
 113     printf(filename);
 115     fptr = fopen (filename, "wb");
 116     printf(fptr);
 118     if (fptr == NULL) {
 119         fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file in.list!\n");
 120         exit(1);
 122     }
 123     for(i = 0; i < num; ++i){
 124         int class = max_index(probs[i], classes);
 125         float prob = probs[i][class];
 126         if(prob > thresh){
 127             //int width = pow(prob, 1./2.)*30+1;
 128             int width = 8;
 129             printf("%s: %.0f%%\n", names[class], prob*100);
 130             fprintf(fptr, "%s,%.0f%%\n", names[class], prob*100);
```

The complete code can be found here: https://gist.github.com/eba1a5a6373b688b1b5d36624c897b90
fptr is not null however no file gets created. How can I fix it?

```
$ ls output/
```

returns nothing!
Note: this line gets printed on the stdout correctly:

```
 129             printf("%s: %.0f%%\n", names[class], prob*100);
```

Comment: I think you have a `.txt` file ...

Comment: take a look to `strcpy` function definition

Comment: the filename is almost printed correctly except it omits output/ from the beginning of filename however it doesn't even create the files in the current directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines:

```
110     strcpy(filename,"output/");
111     strcpy(filename,image_file_name);
112     strcpy(filename, ".txt");
```

does **not** produce a string like `output/some_name.txt`

Each `strcpy` call overwrites what is already in the destination string.

Use **one** `strcpy` and then use `strcat` the other places to append to the string.

OP: This fixed the problem as explained above:

```
 110     strcpy(filename,"output/");
 111     strcat(filename,image_file_name);
 112     strcat(filename, ".txt");
 113     printf(filename);
```